# Interweave .tex files to create single PDF

Tags: pdf, compiling, combine

I have three `.tex` files.

1. contains all the verses in a document in this format: `\subsection*{वृद्धिरादैच् 1.1.1} \label{1.1.1}`
2. contains explanation 1
3. contains explanation 2

Is there a way to merge these three documents to create a single PDF?

To create a single PDF file:

What sort of delimiters do I need to put in document 2 & 3 
to show the explanations 1 & 2 from these documents 
under corresponding verses in document 1?

In document 1 some marker (i.e. rule or exp1 exp2) shall be shown at the start of each explanation.

It would be ideal if I could use two different font sizes.
 [image]

Comment: Please provide more information on how the files need to be merged. Will they be merged sequentially (first verse.tex, then expl-.tex, and finally expl-2.tex), or do the explanations pertaining to a given verse somehow have to be inserted following the corresponding verse?

Comment: Mico- I added an image to my question to show the desired output. The verse appears at the center as I have shown in the image. I have a working tex file upto that point. I need help to display the explanations under the verses as shown in the image.

Comment: Thanks, @Aku. Is each verse is in a LaTeX environment, and are the two groups of explanations (two per verse) also in their own separate environments, say `expli` and `explii`? I believe we still need to get more information from you in order to be able to provide suggestions. E.g., does each verse have to start on a new page, or can it start anywhere on a page? Do the `verses`, `expli`, and `explii` environments define their own layouts -- and what you need is a method for interleaving the environments -- or do you still need to define the layouts? Please provide an MWE.

Comment: @Mico - No, the explanations are not in any environment as of now, So far they are in plain text format.  I want to know how to put them in an environment. Yes each `verse` can start on a new page. Verse are already defined its own layout but there is none for `expli` and `explii`

Comment: Please consider adding a MWE. Incidentally, do the verses and the two types of explanations *have* to reside in three separate files, or is that just a matter of convenience? Could they conceivably reside in 3`N` files separate tex files, named (say) verse-i.tex, explone-i.tex, and expltwo-i.tex, where `N` is the total number of verses and `i` is an index that runs from 1 to `N`? If you had 3`N` separate files, numbered sequentially in the form suggested above, constructing a `for` loop to iterate over all files would become quite simple to do.

Comment: I typed 1200 verse and found good explanation from someone else. Thats how I ended with three files. now creating verse-i.tex, explone-i.tex, and expltwo-i.tex files for each verse would be hard, can spend few days if thats the only way out. I still need to define the layout for the `Expli` and `explii`

Comment: Why do you want to merge PDFs instead of simply "merging" the text files? Consider storing the explanations for the verses in separate files (for each verse) and inputing all these files in the right order.

Comment: @Aku, If i am not wrong, can i consider your problem like this. Say your verse is something like statement of a theorem and the two explanations are something like proof for that theorem.

Comment: @Anil - Yes your understanding is correct. I am sure you would know a "Shloka" or "Doha" and then its explanation

Comment: @Martin - As i said in my previous message, I have more than 1200 verses. Creating 1 file for each with explanation is possible but practically very difficult. There I wanted to put markers in the tex file and compile it into one single pdf.

Comment: @Aku: Put the texts into a database and generate your file for TeX with a program.

Comment: @ Aku, Is the following statement correct, which a programmer can esily understand. You have a theorem (1,2,3,etc) and 2 proofs (1a, 1b, 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b, etc). All these are stored in different tex files (1,2,3 etc in one file, a's and b's in two seperate files). The problem is when you compile, you should have 1, below that 1a and next 1b. Later 2, 2a, 2b in that order. Hope  the experts can solve now.

Answer (score 2):

Interleaving of contents from three different `.tex` files is not easy. If you had control over the contents and can generate it in a systematic way, could could use something like [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) to "import the databases" and then parse them sequentially (interleaved) to obtain your output. Alternatively, you could store the contents of "Explanation 1" and "Explanation 2" in a separate macro and then write them out while you're reading in "Verse". It all depends on the amount of control you have in generating the three files.

---

Here is a small attempt at obtaining the output, using the `datatool` package. However, heed the following warnings from the [`datatool` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool.pdf):

> Whilst TEX is an excellent typesetting language, it is not designed as a
>   database management system, and attempting to use it as such is like
>   trying to fasten a screw with a knife instead of a screwdriver: it can be done, but
>   requires great care and is more time consuming. [...] large databases and complex
>   operations will still slow the time taken to process your document. Therefore, if
>   you can, it is better to do the complex operations using whatever system created
>   the data in the first place.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\usepackage{datatool}% http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool
\begin{filecontents*}{verses.tex}
Name,Label
First,first
Second,second
Last,last
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{expl1.tex}
Label,Explanation
second,This is Explanation~1 for the second verse
first,This is Explanation~1 for the first verse
last,This is Explanation~1 for the last verse
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{expl2.tex}
Label,Explanation
last,This is Explanation~2 for the last verse
first,This is Explanation~2 for the first verse
second,This is Explanation~2 for the second verse
\end{filecontents*}

\newcounter{myverse}
\newenvironment{myverse}[1]
  {% \begin{myverse}
  \refstepcounter{myverse}%
  \addvspace{2\baselineskip}\noindent
  \hfill {\Large\bfseries Verse~--~\themyverse~--~#1} \hfill\null\par\nobreak
  \noindent\hrulefill\par\nobreak
  }{% \end{myverse}
  }
\newenvironment{firstexpl}
  {% \begin{firstexpl}
    \par\nobreak{\large\bfseries Explanation~--~1:}\par\nobreak
  }{% \end{firstexpl}
    \par\hfill\ldots ends here.\par
  }
\newenvironment{secondexpl}
  {% \begin{secondexpl}
    \par\nobreak{\large\bfseries Explanation~--~2:}\par\nobreak
  }{% \end{secondexpl}
    \par\hfill\ldots ends here.\par
  }
\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb{verses}{verses.tex}% Load verses.tex
\DTLloaddb{expl1}{expl1.tex}% Load expl1.tex
\DTLloaddb{expl2}{expl2.tex}% Load expl2.tex

\DTLforeach*{verses}
  {\CurrentVerse=Name,\CurrentLabel=Label}{%
    \begin{myverse}{\CurrentVerse}\label{\CurrentLabel}
      \DTLgetvalueforkey{\explanation}{Explanation}{expl1}{Label}{\CurrentLabel}%
      \begin{firstexpl}\explanation\end{firstexpl}
      \DTLgetvalueforkey{\explanation}{Explanation}{expl2}{Label}{\CurrentLabel}%
      \begin{secondexpl}\explanation\end{secondexpl}
    \end{myverse}
  }
\end{document}
```

Within the `myverse` environment, `datatool` searches for the appropriate explanation associated with that specific verse `Name`. This allows you to have a different order of each explanation (both `expl1.tex` and `expl2.tex`). However, if you maintain the same order as `verses.tex`, you can speed up your compilation and don't need to search for the correct key/entry.

For the sake of completeness, I've added a `Label` for each verse that you can use directly as `\label{\CurrentLabel}` to label the verse.

One limitation of using `datatool` directly, is that it only works with ASCII text files. However, if you need other language support (as suggested by your post), you can store the contents of every verse in a file that you can `\input` based on the conditions in (say) `verses.tex`.

The [`filecontents` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) is loaded to make the example above portable, and may therefore not be needed in your application.

---

Other options also exist, but would require (most likely) external applications to interleave the "databases" into a more manageable document.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that this is the wrong way to do it :)